# How can I convert a part of my data to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to inject some data into a form (ckeditor).
Problem is when I inject it it gives me something like this : 
[image]

As you can see, the image and the title are good, but the description isn't.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(function($) {
    var dialog = window.parent.CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();

    var form       = $('#dynamictemplates-contents');
    var targetHtml = $('input[name=html]').val('');
    var generateHtmlContent = function()
    {
      $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        type: form.attr("method"),
        dataType : 'html',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data, status) {
            targetHtml.val(data);

            // var iframe = $(dialog._.editor.document.$.defaultView.frameElement);
            // iframe.contents().find("head").append('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('backend/js/holder.min.js') }}"></scr' + 'ipt>');

            //dialog._.editor.insertHtml(data);
            //dialog.hide();
        },
        error: function(data, status, error){
          alert('Une erreur a eu lieu lors de la récupération du contenu : "'+data+'"');
        }
      })
    }

    var elmts = form.find('input[type=hidden][name^="content_ids"]');
    if(!elmts.length)
    {
      generateHtmlContent();
    }
    else
    {

      elmts.on('change', function(){
        var submit = true;
        elmts.each(function()
        {
          if(!$(this).val())
            submit = false;
        });

        if(submit)
          generateHtmlContent();
        else
          targetHtml.val('');
      });
    }

  });
</script>
```

I already tried to do

```
targetHtml.val($('<div />').html(data).text());
```

This works for the description, but the title loses its style and the image disappears.

This is the row source of the form :

```
<section class="ckedt-dragrow content recipe">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box img">
            <div class="img-container ckedt-img-to-background" style="background-image:url('/cache/570x380/uploads/image/2015/04/A-FILETTA-PAOLO-FRESU-DANIELE-DI-BONAVENTURA.jpg')">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="box text">
        <div class="title">
            <span>[Genre]</span> <strong>Jérôme Paoli, garde de la réserve</strong>
        </div>
        &lt;section class="ckedt-dragrow content video"&gt; &lt;div class="container"&gt; &lt;div class="box img"&gt; &lt;div class="box-content"&gt; &lt;div class="img-container ckedt-img-to-background" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/570x380')"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class="box text"&gt; &lt;div class="box-content"&gt; &lt;p&gt;Ici, ce n’est pas un mais trois canaux qui parcourent nos paysages, tantôt rectilignes, tantôt onduleux, ils sont autant d’atmosphères contrastées et d’émotions à vivre.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Le Canal du Midi&lt;/strong&gt;, fabuleuse ligne de vie entre les hommes et de commerce entre les régions. Ses 241 km sont une formidable prouesse technique, et ses paysages d’une douceur extrême.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Le Canal de la Robine&lt;/strong&gt;, sur les traces de l’ancien lit du fleuve Aude, il traverse Narbonne et les lagunes avant de rejoindre la Méditerranée.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Le Canal de Jonction&lt;/strong&gt;, comme son nom l’indique, connecte la Canal du Midi à la Robine. Un canal espéré pendant plus d’un siècle.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/section&gt; <a href="/app_dev.php/fr/jerome-paoli-garde-de-la-reserve">+ lire</a></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Have you got an idea how to fix it ?

Comment: can you create a fiddle or can we see it in action please?

Comment: @PhilipBevan Sorry I had never used it and to recreat all my environnement(i use databases, multiple libs ...) it would take more than 5 hours.

Comment: you just need to post one example in the fiddel, instead of db requests and ajax you have just variables with thouse values.. to show what the problem is..

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` give you the text so html is convertet to text, wich is save if you want to prehand cross site scripting (wich can also happen von alternative sources)

see this fiddel:
http://jsfiddle.net/hossain/sUTVg/